# Creating a stored procedure to fill a new table using an existing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to create a new stored procedure to fill a table with 4 columns (Timestamp, Business units, Name, Value). In this new stored procedure, I need to create a cursor that loops over the business units, and in each loop, execute an existing stored procedure with parameters.

I have been provided with .rdl file where the data resides. A history table for the same has to be created in SQL server 2008 R2 with timestamp. The base tables for which the history table is to be created have not been provided.

Comment: question is a work requirement. Make an attempt yourself...

Comment: And while you're trying to do it - try to do it **without** a cursor....

Comment: @AnilSoman: I am just a student who has started learning stored procedures. I created history table with timestamp column and executed the existing stored procedure to fill this table. It is giving me the following error: 'Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Procedure SP_KPI_Report, Line 15
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition'. (P.s. The report from where the data is to be extracted consists of 6 columns.)

Comment: @MitchWheat: I am trying it from last 2 days. But didn't come up with any solution.

Comment: Post your stored procedure and we'll help. The error is your real question, here.

Comment: hi rlb.usa, my problem is i am new to sql server and in learning phase, so i am not able to start. I don't know where to start from. As asked above,  I have to create a new table to store the historical data for each day (timestamp) per business unit(which should be one of the column of my new table). Then i have to create a stored procedure to populate the historical table.

Comment: hey Mitch, i tried many things after googling. But none of 'em helped me. I am not able to start. I just need guidance for startup.

Answer (score 0):

inside a stored procedure you can call another stored procedure like this:

```
SET @paramvalue = 'someValue'
SET @SQLString = N'EXEC Myproc @param ' + @paramvalue

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString
```

not sure if you really need the cursor but make sure it is the last option you use since it comes with a very big performance cost.

Hope this will get you started.